# How do I fix this Unity rendering issue (VMware guest)?

Tags: unity, vmware, screen-corruption

I have just download the Ubuntu desktop and show me this:

[image: http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7035/ubuntuhc.png]

I use the Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you installed Ubuntu and applied all system updates? Have you installed the VMware guest tools?